# Including the div reside in one page in to another in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learner of javascript, wants to include one div reside in another page dynamically on click of particular hyper link there are many hyperlinks, *I have seen many ways to do that on Google :*

iFrames -- it load another page inside one page by changing its src dynamically i thought so that is not the speedy way or efficient way to do that.

javascript -- functions use to generate the div dynamically but my div is reside in another page and I want to "***include it in onclick of hyperlink***"

and can be any other way like jquery functions.

so, suggest me the best way to do that.

Comment: Depends on the content of the page you're trying to insert. If it's just text (from a page on the same domain), see jQuery `.ajax()`.

Comment: @Mooseman The page from I trying to insert the div is another HTML page, yes it belongs to the same domain

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#clickableLink" ).click(
  function(){
    $("#insertableDiv").load( "relative/url/to/page.html" );
  }
);
```